# python wrapper in wrapper - order of execution confusing?

Tags: python-3.x, wrapper

it's my first time posting a question here, hence I'd like to apologise if I'm breaching any rules. thanks

My question is, why is python3 printing
3
1
2
4
 instead of 
3
4
1
2
4 on the following code?
My argument is... if python goes to print 2 [ which implies reading print_two from within print_one ], why didn't python go to print 4 first before going to print 1?

Thanks very much.

```
def print_one(x):
    print(1)
    def print_two():
        print(2)
        return x()
    return print_two

def print_three(x):
    print(3)
    def print_four():
        print(4)

    return print_four

def major_print():
    print("major print")

major_print = print_one(print_three(major_print))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    major_print()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is easy to explain:

The first print statement in both decorating functions are executed as soon as you decorate the function. If you omit the function call, your get the output

```
3
1
```

That is because the inner decorator `print_three` is called first, and `print_one` is decorating the function afterwards.

The print statements inside the wrapper functions (which modify your original function) are executed when the function is called. Because `print_four` does not use the argument of the decorator, you basically just decorate it with `print_two`. So an equivalent to the final function would be something like

```
def major_print():
    print(2)
    print(4)
    return None
```

This way you get said sequence of numbers 3124 as your console output.